# Using Asymptote, how do I rotate the label indicating the length of the side of a triangle?

Tags: asymptote

I have a diagram of a right triangle. I would like the label for the length of the hypotenuse to be typeset in the direction of the hypotenuse.

Also, I would appreciate the code for drawing the right-angle mark in blue and coloring the region enclosed by it yellow.

I wanted to add an arc of a circle indicating the measure of $\angle{QPR}$ is $\theta$. Why doesn't the following code draw the arc?

```
import geometry;    
pen BluePen=blue+1bp;
markangle(O, P, C, radius=8.5mm, BluePen);
```

I didn't include that in the following code to avoid errors in compiling.

```
[asy]
import olympiad;
size(150);
pair P, Q, R;
P = (sqrt(7),1);
Q = (0,0);
R = (sqrt(7),0);
//
draw(P--Q--R--cycle);
//
//
label(scale(0.75)* "$\sqrt{x}$", Q--R, S);
label(scale(0.75)* "$\sqrt{x+1}$", P--Q, NNW);
label(scale(0.75)* "$1$", P--R, E);
label(scale(0.85)* "$P$", P, N);
label(scale(0.85)* "$Q$", Q, S);
label(scale(0.85)* "$R$", R, S);
//
//
//
draw(rightanglemark(P, R, Q, 4));
[/asy]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick way.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(150);
pair P, Q, R;
P = (sqrt(7),1);
Q = (0,0);
R = (sqrt(7),0);
filldraw(box(R,R+.2dir(135)),yellow,black);
draw(arc(P,.2,degrees(R-P),degrees(Q-P)));
path pmark=arc(P,.3,degrees(R-P),degrees(Q-P));
label(scale(0.75)*"$\theta$",relpoint(pmark,.5));
draw(P--Q--R--cycle);
label(scale(0.75)* "$\sqrt{x}$", Q--R, S);
label(Label(scale(0.75)* "$\sqrt{x+1}$",Rotate(P-Q)), P--Q);
label(scale(0.75)* "$1$", P--R, E);
label(scale(0.85)* "$P$", P, NE);
label(scale(0.85)* "$Q$", Q, SW);
label(scale(0.85)* "$R$", R, SE);
```

Comment: What is the "R+.2dir(135)" in the command `box(R,R+.2dir(135))`?

Comment: @user74973 it is a box - a rectangle (in this case, a square) with 2 opposite vertexes are `R` and `R+.2dir(135)` (from `R`, go `.2=2mm` in the direction of `135`)

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, using `perpendicularmark()` from `geometry` module,

```
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import geometry;
void perpMark(picture pic=currentpicture, 
       pair M, pair O, pair B, real size=5, 
       pen p=currentpen, filltype filltype = NoFill){
  perpendicularmark(pic, M,unit(unit(O-M)+unit(B-M)),size,p,filltype);
}

size(150);
pair P, Q, R;
P = (sqrt(7),1);
Q = (0,0);
R = (sqrt(7),0);
perpMark(R, P, Q, Fill(paleyellow));
draw(P--Q--R--cycle);
dot(P--Q--R,UnFill);
label(scale(0.75)* "$\sqrt{x}$", (Q+R)/2, UnFill);
label(rotate(degrees(P-Q))*scale(0.75)* "$\sqrt{x+1}$", (P+Q)/2,UnFill);
label(scale(0.75)* "$1$", (P+R)/2,UnFill);
label(scale(0.85)* "$P$", P, N);
label(scale(0.85)* "$Q$", Q, S);
label(scale(0.85)* "$R$", R, S);
```

[image]

Comment: P.S. It's preferable to use the proper font settings instead of just scaling the `LaTeX` labels.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\scriptsize]
\tzcoors(0,0)(Q){$Q$}[-135]({sqrt(7)},1)(P){$P$}[45]({sqrt(7)},0)(R){$R$}[-45];
\tzpolygon(P){$\sqrt{x+1}$}[sloped,a](Q){$\sqrt x$}[b](R){1}[r](P);
\tzanglemark(Q)(P)(R){$\theta$}(5pt)
\tzrightanglemark*[draw,fill=yellow,opacity=1](Q)(R)(P)(3pt)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```